# CodeIgniter model unable to return specific records

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model, rows

I am using CodeIgniter and I'm unable to get the `where()` selection method to work when using the `results()` method to fetch all the rows from a table.

Here's my model:

```
public function get_all_entries($id)
    {
        // Select row to be fetched
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $this->db->get('users');
        // Execute the find query with provided data
        $query = $this->db->get('users');
        // Return an object with all the data
        return $query->result();
    }
```

It is supposed to return all the rows that match the `$id` argument in the `users` table, but instead, it simply fetches all the records in the table, including those that doesn't match the provided `$id` argument.

What I'm doing wrong here? I've tried the `row()` method and although it works with the `where()` it only returns a single row so it doesn't suit my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the get() method twice, the first one with the where, but is not assign to a variable; the second one is assigned to a variable, but since the where clause is already used by the other one it gets everything. delete the first get and you should be fine.

```
public function get_all_entries($id)
{
    // Select row to be fetched
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    // Execute the find query with provided data
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    // Return an object with all the data
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but there was another issue (if id was zero or not in table) that led me to think this wasn't the solution, now that I fixed that issue, the solution you mentioned works, thank you.

Comment: Could you please give the question an upvote? It's really appreciated.